# Opencv camera access issue when launching flask app on ubuntu20.04 server

Tags: python, opencv, flask, server

I deployed a flask app to my cloud server on linode. I have nginx running static files and gunicorn running the python script. I've also set up a ufw When deployed I click the link which begins the open cv loop but it is unable to access the camera by index 0.

[ WARN:11] global /tmp/pip-req-build-24v3eisa/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (890) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index

When running locally the script runs fine the first time but I need to restart the local server and launch again for it to work. Is there a way I can access the users camera on the server with permission from the user?

Comment: "I deployed a flask app to my cloud server on linode." -- and how do you expect that to connect to your local webcam ?

Comment: It is accesible via ip domain as a web application because flask is a web application framework running on nginx and gunicorn. If I can click a link that interacts with my python script I am assuming there is a way it can interact with the users camera which is exactly what the question is @berak

Comment: "It is accessible via ip domain" -- but you try to open a (local) usb webcam, via id, not url.

Comment: so there is a way to access a devices camera through url. Is there a way to determine what the users devices url is? @berak

Comment: "Is there a way to determine what the users devices url " -- IF it's an actual IP camera, the user (and only that one) will know, but again -- no way with an ordinary usb webcam

Comment: again, if you want to stick with flask, you need a way to acquire images from the *users* cam and send those to your server (maybe using js / html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few answers to my original question about accessing users camera from the front end to the server. I am sure my many python friends who have asked this question will find it useful.

It seems if you want to use Flask you will need to use JS's getusermedia() to access the users camera with permision and stream it back as seen in this digital ocean article;

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/front-and-rear-camera-access-with-javascripts-getusermedia

I also found another method using webrtc on the streamlit docs which seems easier. Only negative is I will have to rebuild the app to streamlit but it is very user friendly and wont be a problem! :)

https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/new-component-streamlit-webrtc-a-new-way-to-deal-with-real-time-media-streams/8669/31

Comment: Update I have finally got it worked out on Streamlit and it is fully functioning with the users web cam accessed through the web page :) Essentially you are building a class that processes the frames for you instead of running it through an opencv while loop. Kind of confusing at first but they have many great examples on the streamlit docs.